# Error (bound method DataFrame.to_string of) - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code is printing something that I have no idea why.
Bellow is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

n = int(input('Type in the number of students: ')) 
d = {}  
for n in range(0, n): 
    nome = input('Type in the name of the student: ')
    n1 = float(input('Type in the first grade of the student: '))
    n2 = float(input('Type in the second grade of the student: '))
    n3 = float(input('Type in the third grade of the student: '))
    n4 = float(input('Type in the fourth grade of the student: '))
    m = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4 
    if m >= 7:  
        a = 'Approved'    
    else:   
        a = 'Failed'   
    d[nome] = ["{:.2f}".format(n1), "{:.2f}".format(n2), "{:.2f}".format(n3), "{:.2f}".format(n4), a]
    print('')   

b = pd.DataFrame(d) 
b = b.T 
print('Grades of the Students\n- - - - - - - - -', end = '')    
print(b.to_string)
```

After the last '-' in the line bellow Grades of the Students, I get this exact message:
"<bound method DataFrame.to_string of            0     1     2     3         4"
And after the last approved or failed it prints >

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: try `print(b.to_string())`

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot Chris!